# Unique NSUserDefaults for each Xcode iOS simulator OS version?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I've recently got my app running for both iOS6 and iOS7. However, I noticed that when loading up the simulator for iOS7 data that was saved in NSUserDefaults while in the iOS6 simulator is not present.

For example, I save a list with this code (while the simulator is running iOS6):

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myList];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"List_v1"];
```

I can easily re-launch the simulator with iOS6 and retrieve my list with no problems using this code:

```
NSData *savedList = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"List_v1"];
myList = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedList];
```

However, if I re-launch the simulator with iOS7 and run the same code to load the list it is no longer available. Does the simulator keep the data separate for each of the OS versions?

Comment: It would seem to be that way, and would make sense. The data might be stored in different formats between OS versions for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, each iOS version has its own folder in:
`/Users/YOUR_USER/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/IOS_VERSION`

Answer (score 1):

Each iOS version (not just iOS 6 or iOS 7, but also iOS 6.1 is stored separately from iOS 6.0) has its data in its own folder. This data is not just the NSUserDefaults but any other data that your app reads/writes from/to disk. They are treated as separate installations, independent of one another.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I was wrong in my understanding. It seems that user defaults only separates devices by OS version. All simulated devices running the same OS version read/write to the same user defaults.

Different OS versions do have different defaults files.

That's something to watch out for. If you save device-dependent settings to defaults, you could get very messed up testing on the sim.

That's Maddy for pointing this out.

Comment: This isn't right. All simulated devices for a given iOS version in the simulator share the same data. Run the non-retina iPhone simulator for iOS 7.0 and then the retina iPad simulator for iOS 7.0 and you will see the same apps, the same NSUserDefaults, etc. The simulator only has separate folders per version of iOS, not per device.

Comment: Really? I need to test this then.

Comment: @maddy, you are absolutely right. Thank you for correcting me. I was assuming, not testing. My bad.